# In R/Shiny how to display different TabsetPanels by clicking on buttons and starting displaying the first one

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to start my app with the first tabset panel displayed.

To do this I need to click on `TabSet 1 button`. How can I let this TabSet displayed without need to click on the `TabSet 1 button` ?

And also, to do the changing on tabSet Panels I use `observeEvent`for times. Is this the best practice to do this?

How can I improve the `observeEvent`code part?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("btn_1", "tabSet 1"),
  actionButton("btn_2", "tabSet 2"),
  
  actionButton("btn_3", "tabSet 3"),
  actionButton("btn_4", "tabSet 4"),
  
  uiOutput("tabset")
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
 observeEvent(input$btn_1,{
    
    output$tabset  <- renderUI({
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel(
          h6("TabPanel 1")
        ),
        tabPanel(
          h6("TabPanel 2")
        ),
        tabPanel(
          h6("TabPanel 3")
        ),
        tabPanel(
          h6("TabPanel 4")
        )
        
      )
    })
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$btn_2,{
    
    output$tabset  <- renderUI({
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel(
          h6("TabPanel 1")
        )
        
      )
    })
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$btn_3,{
    
    output$tabset  <- renderUI({
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel(
          h6("TabPanel 3")
        ),
        
        tabPanel(
          h6("TabPanel 3")
        ),
        
        tabPanel(
          h6("TabPanel 3")
        ),
        
        tabPanel(
          h6("TabPanel 3")
        ),
        
        tabPanel(
          h6("TabPanel 3")
        )
        
        
      )
    })
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$btn_4,{
    
    output$tabset  <- renderUI({
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel(
          h1("LASt Button Title Panel")
        )
        
        
      )
    })
    
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to avoid `renderUI` when ever you can, as it is slow to re-render all those elements on a button click compared to switching their visibility on and off.

Please read [chapter 10](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-dynamic.html#action-dynamic) from *Mastering Shiny*:

> That’s because it’s reactive: the app must load, trigger a reactive
> event, which calls the server function, yielding HTML to insert into
> the page. This is one of the downsides of renderUI(); relying on it
> too much can create a laggy UI.

You could use `radioButtons` and `conditionalPanel`s or simply a nested `tabsetPanel` to keep the work in the UI part of the app (client side):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel(
      "tabSet 1",
      tabsetPanel(tabPanel(h6("TabPanel 1")),
                  tabPanel(h6("TabPanel 2")),
                  tabPanel(h6("TabPanel 3")),
                  tabPanel(h6("TabPanel 4"))
      )
    ),
    tabPanel("tabSet 2",
             tabsetPanel(tabPanel(h6(
               "TabPanel 1"
             )))
    ),
    tabPanel(
      "tabSet 3",
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel(h6("TabPanel 3")),
        tabPanel(h6("TabPanel 3")),
        tabPanel(h6("TabPanel 3")),
        tabPanel(h6("TabPanel 3")),
        tabPanel(h6("TabPanel 3"))
      )
    ),
    tabPanel("tabSet 4",
             tabsetPanel(tabPanel(
               h1("LASt Button Title Panel")
             ))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```